# Heroku could not find rake-13.0.6 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bundle, rake

I have a simple rake task that works locally but doesn't work on Heroku. It complains about not finding `rake-13.0.6`

```
➜  mw_wines_feed git:(master) heroku run rake mw_wines:import_feed
Running rake mw_wines:import_feed on ⬢ mw-wines-feed... up, run.7472 (Hobby)
Could not find rake-13.0.6 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I've tried `bundle install` and pushing to master however no changes.
Gemfile has that rake version:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.6'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '>= 4.0.0.rc1'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# ActiveModel::Type::Integer uses 4 bytes, but our databases use 8. So we explicitly pass that limit of 8 to the appropriate ActiveRecord::Type constructor and recalculate the range. Now, e.g., Fabricate, won't complain anymore that:
gem 'active_record_fix_integer_limit'

gem 'addressable'

gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]

gem 'google_drive'

gem 'googleauth'

gem 'rake', '13.0.6'
```

Comment: 1. Check if the branch you have deployed has the gem in gemfile
2. Try redeploying the branch

Comment: Yes, did that already. Same output unfortunately.

Comment: Rake is a dependency of Rails. Is there a reason you have it explicitly in the Gemfile as well? Do you need a different version from the one Rails uses or something?